# Implement row level permissions in multiple database django

Tags: django, database, permissions, django-guardian, cross-database

I have to implement row-level permissions(object level) in Django, I find out that **Django-guardian** is a good option for this but problem is that I am using multiple databases in project one database has user table while another database has the table on which I want row-level permission and Django-guardian mentioned that they don't support multiple databases
and many-to-many is also not an option because Django does not support that across the database.

Is there any other way to implement this